# How to change the layer order of divs

Tags: css, html

I have 2 divs with the following class names: "red" and "green"
The green div is hidden but when the mouse hovers over the red div, the green div appears.
However, the green div is appearing in front of the red one. I would like to reverse the order so that when hovering over the red div, the green one appears beneath it i.e. I want the red div to overlap the green div (I don't simply want a space between the 2 divs, I want the red div to be over the green one). I actually want to include a background PNG inside the red div so that when the green div appears it is actually underneath the PNG.

The green div is nested inside the red div and my CSS is as follows:

```
.green{
    display: none;
}

.red:hover .green{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: And the position property.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: This would (probably) be easier to answer if you showed us the HTML, rather than described it to us. Code reduces ambiguity inherent in natural language, and leads to infinitely better/more reliable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can hover over the red div since it's nested inside the green div and that one is hidden, therefor the red div should be hidden too.

But I changed some things.
I used `position`, `z-index` and nested the green inside the red div.

HTML

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="green">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.green {
    display: none;
    background: green;
    width: 310px;
    height: 310px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
.red {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.red:hover .green {
    display: block;
}
```

I made the size of the green div a little bigger and added some margin so it would be visible.

Here's a live example http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/FpsuA/

Answer (score 2):

you can change the order of layers with `z-index`

if you always want the red on to be on top and not put some text on it make it like this:

```
z-index:9999;
```

if you want to know more about it, use this tutorial: [z-index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

Comment: why did I got a -1? could you explain me why?

Comment: well, it does. but the downvote is already gone. maybe it was some missclick of him/her :)

Comment: @Ryan de VriesThanks. I still can't seem to get it to work even with values of 9999 and 1. I am going to start over from a blank document and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
}
.red {
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#d42046;
    z-index:2;
}
.green {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #1cc477;
    z-index:1;
}
.wrapper:hover .green {
    display: block;  
}
```

**DEMO:**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RSTE9/1/)